# Query QWINSTA in C#

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

So I while back I had to detect the routings in C# for which I used the following code.

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            string destination = queryObj["Destination"].ToString();
            string mask = queryObj["Mask"].ToString();
            string metric = queryObj["Metric1"].ToString();
            string interfaceIndex = queryObj["InterfaceIndex"].ToString();
            string nexthop = queryObj["NextHop"].ToString();
            ...
        }
```

Now I wan't to be able to logoff a remote desktop session. I Know I can do this with qwinsta commands in but I was wondering if there was some way I can get the results of qwinsta into C# like the solution above for netstat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found you can use the Cassia library to retrieve the session ID for the specific server

```
        ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer(serverName))
        {
            server.Open();
            foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
            {
                 NTAccount account = session.UserAccount;
                if (account != null)
                {
                    if (account.ToString() == username)
                    {
                        Disconnect(serverName, session.SessionId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and with the above code you can extract the required info for  the disconnect. How that disconnect has to be preformed is still a mistery to me because when I call the logoff command through C# I get an error.

---

*** EDIT ***

For those intrested, I've found the way to logoff from the remote server through code without using logoff.exe

```
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSLogoffSession(IntPtr hServer, int SessionId, bool bWait);
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

    private void Disconnect(string serverName, int sessionId)
    {
        IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(serverName);
        WTSLogoffSession(server, sessionId, false);
    }
```

Comment: I just want to add that using Cassia manager.GetLocalServer()  did not work for me but manager.GetRemoteServer("localhost") did the trick